# Ruby Gem install creates empty folder in gem directory

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems

I first discovered this when I downloaded a gem and attempted to build it. It builds fine with no errors.  I do a gem install and it says it installs properly.  I attempted to require it using irb and it tells me not found. I did a gem list and it shows up. Finally I looked in the gem folder and there is an entry for the gem there, however looking in the gem folder it is empty.

I attempted to install an online gem azimutto and it is also an empty folder.

I am at a loss as to why installing a downloaded git repository of a gem does not install properly.

I am using RVM and have re-installed it.

Comment: are you looking at the `INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: <path>` that outputs when you do `$ gem environment` ?

Comment: Yesm the same one rvm gemdir says they should be in.  Others are in there. The gem file after build is a reasonable size.  The folder in the gem directory is 6 bytes and nothing in in. I have build many gems from github plus written my own.  I have never seen this.  I got it on a public one also.

I can install it from rubygems. just when I download and build it myself with no changes.

Comment: nothing new on this?

Comment: can you provide a link to the gem/github-repo in question? I do not know a solution, but am very interested to find one.

Comment: I have the same issue, but for me it happens when installing newer versions of bundler on Debian Buster (10). No solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

This question can be answered with Occam's Razor....

The reason that the Ruby Gem you're installing (Azimutto) is creating an empty directory, is because its not programmed properly.

Take a look at the Gem page on [Ruby Gems](https://rubygems.org/gems/azimutto). The one and only version of it was released in August 2013, its only been downloaded 2,545 times, the link to the Gem homepage just redirects to Twitter, the link to its documentation goes to an empty web page, and there is no repo on Github anymore (I searched directly on Github for it).

The solution to your problem is to not use this Gem.